# Form losing focus in c#

Tags: c#

I have a main form, which opens form A, where from form A I can open form B, where from form B I can open form C. The problem is that if I open till form B, everything works fine, but if I open form C as well, and then close Form C and B, form A goes behind the main form. For the forms I m just creating an instance of the form and then use `.Show()`

```
cNewForm form = new cNewForm();
form.Show();
```

I m doing this for every form

Comment: it is your intent to show the forms modeless (so you can access any form at any time)? or did you intend them to be stacked as you describe? If you intended them to be stacked (can't use form B until form C is closed, etc...) then you could try using .ShowDialog() instead.

Comment: You could use the BringToFront method to resolve your issue. Is the main windows with the TopMost property set?

Comment: David, I need them modeless, in factactually they are being that way, he only problem is that when I open the last form, close it, and then clsoe form B, form A just goes behind the main

Comment: If I use the BringToFront  on form A, it will always be on front, I needed them to be seperate windows, but opened from each other

Comment: Is form B being created from the main form? Check the Owner is form A and not the main form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not set the window ownership properly because you are using the no parameter version of `Show()`. You need to set the owner by calling the [`Show()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) overload that receives an owner parameter. Alternatively you can set the [`Owner`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.owner.aspx) property directly, but it's much better to do so when you call `Show()`.

The window owner is an important Win32 concept. I recommend reading the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632599.aspx#owned_windows) on the subject.

> - An owned window is always above its owner in the z-order.
> - The system automatically destroys an owned window when its owner is destroyed.
> - An owned window is hidden when its owner is minimized.

In your case I think you want form A to be owned by your main form, and form B to be owned by form A, and form C to be owned by form B.

Comment: Actually the problem was solved by setting Form Border Style to Sizable, any body knows why??

Comment: Possibly because that led to a re-creation of the window handle and the owner was set correctly. The behaviour you describe is for sure down to incorrect owner. Note bullet point 1. If the owner was set correctly, your reported behaviour could not occur.

Answer (score 1):

I have often found that these kinds of issues are resolved by assigning owners to windows. When you show the window:

```
FormA formA = new FormA();
formA.Show(this); // assuming this code is in the main form
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use the `ShowDialog();` methode instead of `show()` in order to show it as a modal form. see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: Presumably `Show` was chosen because the design is for the form to be modeless.