# Parent Form is losing focus after closing a loading form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've searched countless questions in and outside stackoverflow and I haven't seen any answers that fixed my problem

I have the same scenario with the question -> [Form losing focus in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14626919/form-losing-focus-in-c-sharp)

My form structure is like this

login Form(first form)

                        |
Dashboard Form(hides login form after load)
               |
      Admin Form 

Below is the code regarding with the form changes I do

Hiding login form:

```
    private async void Dashboard_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Enabled = false;
      login loginpage = Application.OpenForms.OfType<login>().FirstOrDefault();
      await Task.Run(async () =>
      {
        using (OleDBConn helper = new OleDBConn())
        {
          helper.OleDBHelper();
          await helper.OpenConnAsync();
        }
      });
      loginpage.Hide();
      loginpage.TopMost = false;
      Enabled = true;
      DateTimeTick.Start();
    }
```

Loading Admin Form from a click of a button in the Dashboard:

```
    private void LoadPanel(Form newForm)
    {
      if (previousForm != null)
      {
        previousForm.Dispose();
      }

      previousForm = newForm;

      newForm.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
      newForm.TopLevel = false;
      panelContainer.Controls.Clear();
      panelContainer.Controls.Add(newForm);
      newForm.Show();
    }

    private void btnAdmin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      Admin frm = new Admin();
      LoadPanel(frm);
    }
```

Lastly on Admin Load:

```
    private async void Admin_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      la = new LoadingAlert("LOADING COMPANIES");
      la.Show(this);
      Dashboard.Enabled = false;
      Enabled = false;
      companyGrid.Rows.Clear();
      await Task.Delay(100);
      List<string[]> company_data = await Task.Run(async () => { return await LoadCompanyAsync(); });
      if (company_data != null)
      {
        foreach (var data in company_data)
        {
          companyGrid.Rows.Add(data);
          cbCompany.Items.Add(data[1]);
        }
      }
      la.Close();
      Dashboard.Enabled = true;
      Enabled = true;
    }
```

The problem occurs with the closing of `LoadingAlert` where after it closes, the whole Application goes behind other applications that is currently opened. I've tried `TopMost` but it is not ideal because it blocks other applications from being shown on top of my Application. I have an idea that the `Ownership` should fix the problem but I've tried some fixes but no luck. I hope I explained my case. Thanks in advance

Edit:
[image: Example]
Explanation:
As you can see, I placed a window behind the application which is the task manager. Whenever the `LoadingAlert` is closed, the Main Form goes behind.

Comment: Is form closing?  There is a difference between Show() and ShowDialog().  Do you need to keep form open after returning?  You may need to capture form closing event.  See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34975508/reach-control-from-another-page-asp-net

Comment: @MustafaÖzçetin ShowDialog() blocks the Execution of the code below it until the form is closed

Comment: @jdweng what form are referencing exactly? And Yes I need to keep the form opened as  the LoadingAlert is just a Loading Screen and should disappear after the necessary execution is done.

Comment: I think issue is with : newForm.Show();  The Show() method will close on return unless you keep form open or use ShowDialog().  But ShowDialog() does not return unless you close the form.  You need to keep the form open after returning so you can read the data on the form.

Comment: @jdweng I do have controls on the LoadingAlert which are a PictureBox and a label.

Comment: I added a gif for reference @jdweng

Comment: Move the Hide() call *after* enabling the form.  That avoids the split second where none of the windows can receive the focus, forcing the OS to pick one from another app.

Comment: @HansPassant Is it the Close() instead of Hide()?

Comment: Did you try removing both `loginpage.Hide();` and `loginpage.TopMost = false;` and use `loginpage.Close();` only in the `Dashboard_Load()` method?

Comment: I don't have any problem regarding with the loginpage and other things. I only have problems within the Admin_Load

Comment: Please kindly check the video I attached above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Hans Passant's Answer quote

> Move the Hide() call after enabling the form. That avoids the split second where none of the windows can receive the focus, forcing the OS to pick one from another app.

Although I am pointing out the closing of `LoadingAlert`. Changing the flow of the code from

```
      la.Close();
      Dashboard.Enabled = true;
      Enabled = true;
```

to

```
      Dashboard.Enabled = true;
      Enabled = true;
      la.Close();
```

Fixes the problem. 
My guess is I am modifying something from the previous forms after closing the most recent or the previous form's state is Disabled and that's why it's losing it's Focus when the `LoadingAlert` is closed.

If there's any more insights on what might be the real case here, I'll mark it as a answer. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, there is a `LoginForm` that is shown first, where a successful login will show the `DashboardForm`.

[image: Login flow]

Then, by clicking on [Show Admin Form], the `AdminForm` should go on top and *stay there even if it loses focus by clicking back on the dashboard*.

[image: form activations]

I made a repo you can [Clone](https://github.com/IVSoftware/dashboard-with-login-and-admin-form.git) to make sure it has the behavior you want.

---

What has worked for me when the main form (e.g. `DashboardForm`) is 'not' the first form shown is to force the creation of the Handle in the costructor so that the application is clear that it is the main window of the app. This way, calling `AdminForm.Show(this)` has the correct owner and maintains the ZOrder.

```cs
public partial class DashboardForm : Form
{
    private LoginForm LoginForm { get; } = new LoginForm();
    private AdminForm AdminForm { get; } = new AdminForm();

    public DashboardForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // Ordinarily we don't get the handle until
        // window is shown. But we want it now.
        _ = Handle;
        // Call BeginInvoke on the new handle so as not to block the CTor.
        BeginInvoke(new Action(() => execLoginFlow()));
        // Ensure final disposal of child forms. 
        Disposed += (sender, e) =>
        {
            LoginForm.Dispose();
        };
        buttonSignOut.Click += (sender, e) => IsLoggedIn = false;
        AdminForm.FormClosing += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if(e.CloseReason == CloseReason.UserClosing)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                AdminForm.Hide();
            }
        };
        buttonShowAdminForm.Click += (sender, e) => AdminForm.Show(this);
    }
    private void execLoginFlow()
    {
        Visible = false;
        while (!IsLoggedIn)
        {
            LoginForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            if (DialogResult.Cancel == LoginForm.ShowDialog(this))
            {
                switch (MessageBox.Show(
                    this,
                    "Invalid Credentials",
                    "Error",
                    buttons: MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel))
                {
                    case DialogResult.Cancel: Application.Exit(); return;
                    case DialogResult.Retry: break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                IsLoggedIn = true;
            }
        }
    }

    bool _isLoggedIn = false;
    public bool IsLoggedIn
    {
        get => _isLoggedIn;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isLoggedIn, value))
            {
                _isLoggedIn = value;
                onIsLoggedInChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    private void onIsLoggedInChanged()
    {
        if (IsLoggedIn)
        {
            // WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            Text = $"Welcome {LoginForm.UserName}";
            Visible = true;
        }
        else execLoginFlow();
    }
}
```

Comment: That's very comprehensive show of login and admin form. I created a [repo](https://github.com/Kitsunejasutin/Form-losing-focus) that corresponds to the problem I had. With the answer I provided, it is now fixed and working as intended